# What does "You play you pay!" mean?

Tags: phrases, american-english

Actually it's from the comedy show, [Weird Loners](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weird_Loners).

What does "You play you pay!" mean? Thanks.

[image: Phone image]

Text from phone :

> Where's my money ?
>
> I know where you live.
>
> **You play you pay!**
>
> 1K tomorrow.
>
> In case you don't pay which is your favorite kidney?

Comment: You misread the text. It actually says "you pay you play!" Look [here](http://www.afterellen.com/tv/426323-weird-loners-recap-1-3-pay-toll). Then the meaning is obvious

Comment: I didn't. It's "you play you pay" though. Thank. By the way, I still don't get it..

Comment: The person receiving the text is being threatened by a bookie (bookmaker) with whom he evidently placed a bet and whom he now owes $1,000. The bookie asks, “Where’s my money? I know where you live!” as a threat, and then states that, “You play you pay”, which is equivalent to, “If you play [= place bets and gamble money], then you have to pay [the money back if you lose]”. He wants his $1,000 by the next day, otherwise he is going to cut out one of Stosh’s kidneys and take that instead.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a mishearing of the phrase that the questioner is asking about. To save the question from being closed, the questioner should revise the phrase given in the question so that it matches the phrase actually used in the reference comedy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's indeed

> You play, you pay.

It's a shortened version of

> If you play (and you lose), you (have to) pay your debts.

or simply, *you cannot play (get something) without paying*; a sentiment that is also expressed as **TINSTAAFL**:

> There is no such thing as a free lunch.

Answer (score 0):

Using *Blackjack* as an example, here the person is being blunt and saying that if you're playing, you are risking your money and may ultimately lose it.

Comment: Since it's a bookie demanding money, it's not risking -- he already lost the bet and has to pay.